# Log bluetooth from connected phone

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth

How can I log the bluetooth informations, that my connected Android phone sends to another device, so I can see, what it sends and receives? (I'm using Linux btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Android device is connected to your Linux machine and you want to see the packets being sent, your best bet is the "btmon" command. In a new terminal, simply type

```
sudo btmon
```

and then proceed with connecting/exchanging data normally. You'll see the HCI logs on the btmon terminal. More information can be found here:-

- [Scanning for Linux Beacons on the Linux Command Line](https://ukbaz.github.io/howto/beacon_scan_cmd_line.html)
- [btmon
  usage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bluez/btmon.1.en.html)

If on the other hand your Android phone is connected to another device and you want to read the packets through your Linux machine, then you'll need a packet sniffer for this such as Wireshark. More information can be found here:-

- [Analyzing Bluetooth Low Energy Traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640581/analyzing-bluetooth-low-energy-traffic)
- [What is a good solution to capture Bluetooth traffic](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/4313/what-is-a-good-solution-to-capture-bluetooth-traffic/)
- [How to capture/dump Bluetooth LE Link Layer packets in linux without sniffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030382/how-to-capture-dump-bluetooth-le-link-layer-packets-in-linux-without-sniffer)

I hope this helps.